# HTTP fails on Inetsim

Tags: http, ubuntu, installation, malware-detection

I'm trying to set up a malware analysis lab, following the instructions found here:

https://blog.christophetd.fr/malware-analysis-lab-with-virtualbox-inetsim-and-burp/

In setting up inetsim to simulate internet protocols, I keep getting "http_tcp_80 - failed!" everytime I run it.  Changing the port it uses in the configuration file to 8080 causes the it to work. When I run it on a different vm, the configuration works as intended.

I have apache also installed on this vm.  Could it be interfering?

Edit: I just installed a new vm to try using inetsim without apache installed. HTTP is reported to be running, but now dns_53_tcp_udp is reported to be failing to start.  Trying to browse web pages to bring up inetsim's default page fails, regardless of if I use the FQDN or the IP address.  The only time I get the page is with localhost.  Otherwise, I get server not found.  At least I know its not apache.

The error I get with DNS indicates that the 0.0.0.0 ip is already in use, which doesn't make sense to me since 0.0.0.0 is being used to bind the services to all IPs.  Changing the inetsim.conf file so "service_bind_address 10.0.0.0" instead of "service_bind_address 0.0.0.0" seems to run dns, but the browser on both the analysis machine and the victim machine still report no server found.

Comment: i'm trying to bind inetsim to cuckoo but i have a similar issue: http and https don't start.
if i use inetsim in a clean vm all services start

Comment: the problem, in my case, is with nginx

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the Apache server:

```
service apache2 stop
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are some other processes listening on those ports.

Use

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

It will print out those processes with their `pid`. For example, `964` is the `pid` of the first process in this case:

[image]

Check if something is occupying your corresponding ports. Shut them down with

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

Of course, the busy processes running on those ports may not in listening states but still be able to cause such a problem. So you can check it with

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

just in case.

Anyway, it does work for me.